# How to execute a Bash script multiple times in parallel with different arguments each time?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I haven't explained this question enough so it was misunderstood as duplicate.

I want to read N lines each time of a CSV file and execute a script that operates the lines (names). How can I send N lines as an argument to another script and execute it in parallel?

The file is a CSV with +400000 lines like this:

```
nombre,ape_paterno,ape_materno
ALFREDO,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
ANGEL,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
CARLOS,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
DANIEL,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
EDUARDO,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
ELIZABETH,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
FERNANDO ,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
FRANCISCA,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
FRANCISCO ,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
FRANCISCO JAVIER,AGUILAR,AGUILAR
...
```

I want something like this:

```
{
read 
while IFS="," read $N lines
do 
   sh ${DIR}/Downloader.sh $N-Lines-as-argument &
done } < "$input"
wait
```

I have tried the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash) but my result gives null.

Comment: It is a duplicate, did you try answers from any of those other page?

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: @Inian Yes, my output is null.

Comment: @anubhava GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)

Comment: @forkfork: Can you show your attempted code in question that is giving null output

Comment: @forkfork: Why can't you try this _accepted_ answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323931/5291015 from the other duplicated post?

Comment: @Inian: That answer has an unnecessary use of extra file handle. My preference is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31528581/548225)

Comment: @forkfork : Wouldn't `xargs` do exactly what you want? It can split up the input in chunks of lines, pass them to another command, and even parallelizes it if you want to. Look at the *xargs* man page on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script in BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=50 # number of line to read every time

while read -r && arr=("$REPLY"); do
   # read n-1 lines using a for loop
   for ((i=1; i<n; i++)); do
      read -r && arr+=("$REPLY")
   done
   # call your script using 50 element array as argument
   bash ${DIR}/Downloader.sh "${arr[@]}" &
done < file
```