# Script for Reading lines from a file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file of 1000 lines. I need to read that file 10/20 lines per time and execute those or save it into other file. Next time it should read the file from 11/21 and do the same.This should be done till the EOF.

How should I restrict the number while reading from file?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a range of lines from a file with several tools. One of them would be `sed`. The syntax for extracting lines 10 to 20, for instance, would be `sed -n '10,20p' input.txt`. As you are not quite clear about all the details of your desired output, here a solution that uses a `for`-loop:

```
N=$(cat input.txt | wc -l)
di=10
((di1=di+1))
for ((i=1; i<=N; i+=di1)); do
   ((j=i+di))
   sed -n "${i},${j}p" input.txt > output${i}.txt
done
```

This creates new files called `outputX.txt`, where `X` is the number of the first line of the block in `input.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will read 'N' lines (user input from console) at a time from the file "input-file.txt", and execute them each line at a time and can store them into a new file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create new file handle 5
exec 5< input-file.txt

read_n() { for i in $(seq $1); do read || return; echo $REPLY; done; }

echo "Enter the number of lines to read each time"
read N

while lines="$(read_n $N)" ; do

# executing N lines one by one.
while read -r line; do
   echo "Executing \" $line \" command"
   exec "$line" &
   echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
done <<< "$lines"

# saving the N lines to another file.
echo "$lines"  >> output-file.txt

done <&5

# Close file handle 5
exec 5<&-
```

Please also see: [Read n lines at a time using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash)

Answer (score 0):

The following awk solution will print lines in batches of 10 lines at a time:

```
awk '{ data[NR]=$0 } END { strt=1;for ( i=strt;i<=NR;i=i+10 )  { end=strt+9;for ( p=strt;p<=end;p++) { print data[p] } strt=end+1 } }'  filename
```

We first put all the data in an array and then loop through the array with 2 loops. The first dictates the lines of 20 and then the second prints the lines in these batches ( you can do what ever other processing is required here)