# How to pipe tail -f to iconv cmmand?

Tags: encoding, pipe, tail, iconv

I have a log file encoding with gbk, I have to read the data like this:

```
tail -n 2000 nohup.out | iconv -f gbk -t utf-8
```

but when I use `tail -f` it will print nothing:

```
tail -f nohup.out | iconv -f gbk -t utf-8
```

Answer (score 8):

In a similar situation I use a script that reads each line and convert. In your case:
tail -f nohup.out | iconv.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#iconv.sh
IFS=''
while read line
do 
    echo "$line" | iconv -f gbk -t utf-8
done  < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Comment: This worked great for following a UTF-16 log generated by a Windows 10 PowerShell script from WSL Linux.

Comment: Better to buffer more lines at once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash