# Bash script to work with a file list txt file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a txt file which contain a big list of files. Each filename is 1 row in the list.

I was able to read it like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
in="${1:-file.txt}"

[ ! -f "$in" ] && { echo "$0 - File $in not found."; exit 1; }

while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "Copy $file ..."
done < "${in}"
```

What I actually want to achieve in the end is to read these lines, then issue cp command for first 20 or 30 or them, and then delete them from the file.txt and then do again same thing.

Comment: Could you explain in more what your main problem is ? Is it how to read a file 20 lines by 20 lines ?

Comment: So read 20 lines, then copy the files, thenread the next 20 lines `hen delete them from the file.txt` That's strange, what for? Just read 20 lines at a time, no need to delete them from input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read n lines at a time using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash)

Comment: (the answer by gniourf_gniourf using `mapfile` should be the way to go)

Comment: after i read the line, i issue cp command and copy that file and then want to delete from the list because i want to know which were processed already, that was the reason. Basically the file contains 50k rows so i don t wand issue 50k cp at one time...

Answer (score 1):

With `readarray` you can easily read a count of lines of input at a time:

```
while readrray -n 20 -t lines; do
    for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
         echo "Copy $file ..."
    done
done < "${in}"
```